# Shiny datatable keep selected row only.. error: Comparison of these types is not implemented

Tags: r, events, datatable, shiny, reactive

I have a datatable and I want users to be able to select a row and have only that selected row stay displayed, if they deselect the row then it will show all rows again (the reason is I'd like to use the extra real estate after filtered for additional charts)... but I keep running into errors.

Most examples show how to use events and observations to display the selected row or its values, but I can't find anything on how to pass the row selection back as a filter.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    column(8, dataTableOutput("table"))
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    df <- reactive({
      if       (length(input$table_rows_selected) > 0)
      iris%>%
        filter(Species == iris[input$table_rows_selected]) 
      else iris             
      })

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      df()})

  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to show only the selected row. It works by creating a second table to show the selected row. If the user click on the only row of the second table, the full table will be shown.

```R
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    column(8, uiOutput("tables_UI"))
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    v <- reactiveValues(row = 0)

    output$tables_UI  <- renderUI({
      if (v$row == 0) {
        DTOutput("table1")
      } else {
        DTOutput("table2")
      }
    })

    observeEvent(input$table1_rows_selected, {
      v$row <- input$table1_rows_selected
    })

    observeEvent(input$table2_rows_selected, {
      v$row <- 0
    })

    output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      iris})

    output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      if (v$row > 0) {
        iris[v$row, ]
      }
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't tell you how helpful this is, I really appreciate it!